# Solving the recurrence relation for rod cutting problem (without DP) using iteration method

Tags: algorithm, iteration, dynamic-programming, recurrence

I'm going through the Dynamic Programming chapter in the CLRS book. In the rod cutting problem, [this recurrence relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAoqa.jpg) is obtained when we don't use dynamic programming (with base case T(0) = 1). The solution is directly given as T(n) = 2^n.

I can verify that the solution is correct using induction. But I can't seem to figure out how to arrive at this solution step-by-step from the given recurrence using iteration (plug and chug) method. I would really appreciate some help on this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
T(0) = 1

T(1) = 1 + T(0)
     = 2

T(2) = 1 + T(0) + T(1)
       \_,____/
     = T(1) + T(1)
     = 2*T(1)
     = 4

T(3) = 1 + T(0) + T(1) + T(2)
       \_,___________/
     = T(2) + T(2)
     = 2*T(2)
     = 8

T(4) = 1 + T(0) + T(1) + T(2) + T(3)
       \_,__________________/
     = T(3) + T(3)
     = 2*T(3)
     = 16

:

T(n) = 2*T(n-1) = 2^n
```